# How to generate PDF from .tex in browser, using memoir document class?

Tags: javascript, pdf, latex, single-page-application

I'm writing a single-page web-app custom data editor, which currently does not require any server side code to function.

The app generates a .tex file as output. The generated file uses memoir document class and does some complex formatting stuff that is hard to reproduce outside of a *TeX ecosystem.

I would like to let users download PDFs, not .tex files.

I would prefer to generate these PDFs in browser, client-side. I would settle for server-side generation though.

I tried texlive.js, but it lacks memoir. As for the server side, I would like to avoid setting a tex to pdf generation pipeline from scratch --- I feel that it would be a security nightmare.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you considered trying to compile pdflatex (from texlive) to javascript (asm.js) using the emscripten compiler? I think it's worth a try.

Comment: @PeterSalomonsen thats exactly what `texlive.js` is. The `LaTeX` compiler converted to `js` by `asm`. But you have to inject the `TeX` packages at compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you just have to compile your own version of `texlive.js`.

The instructions are [here](https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js/wiki#im-getting-an-error-message-like--latex-error-file--not-found). Just add the [memoir](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) package.

Server side renderers do [exist](https://github.com/aslushnikov/latex-online). However I would recommend to auto-generate a VM for every run. Like CI-tools do it.